# Find the values of $p$ and $q$ which satisfy the probability of exactly $i$ cars

Tags: discrete-mathematics

There are two lanes of cars at a a set of traffic lights, $A$ and $B$. Let $A_i$ denote there are at least $i$ cars in lane $A$ and $B_i$ denote there are at least $i$ cars in the lane $B$

The events $A_i$ and $B_i$ have the
following probabilities,

$Pr(A_i) = 0.8^i$

$Pr(B_i) = 0.6^i$

The probability that there are exactly $i$ cars in lane $A$ can be expressed as $p\times q^i$. Find the values of $p$ and $q$.

CASE 1: This is what I believe to be the correct solution:

$$P( A_i\cap \overline{A_{i+1}} )= P(A_{i}) - P(A_i\cap A_{i+1})\\$$
  $$= P(A_{i}) - P(A_{i+1})\text{ since one is a subset of the other}$$
     $$= 0.8^i-0.8^{i+1}$$
     $$ = 0.8^i-(0.80) \times 0.8^{i}$$
       $$= 0.20\times 0.80^i$$

Therefore, $ p = 0.20$ and $q = 0.80$.

CASE 2: What I can't understand however is why the following doesn't give the same answer.

$$P( A_i\cap \overline{A_{i+1}} )= P(A_{i}) \times P(\overline{A_{i+1}})\\$$
$$= P(A_{i}) \times [1 - P(A_{i+1})]\\$$
$$= 0.8 \times (1 - 0.8^{i+1})\\$$

Evaluating both case 1 and 2 at $i = 2$ we get,

CASE 1:
$$0.20\times 0.80^2 = 0.128$$

CASE 2: 
$$0.8 \times (1 - 0.8^{3}) = 0.390\\$$

To me case 1 and 2 look the same mathematically. The only difference really is the fact I've considered one to be a subset of the other, but I can't see how that simplification makes the two answer drastically different.

What am I missing in case 2 that gives me the wrong answer?

Comment: You're making the assumption in the second one that $A_n$ and $A_{n+1}$ are independent, when you try to compute their probability as a product. They are not at all independent.

Comment: So they're not independent because, for example, if you have $A_{7}$, the probability of having $A_6$ at the same time is zero?

Comment: Well, that's the idea why they're NOT independent, but yeah, if you do not have $A_6$, the probability of having $A_7$ is $0$.

Comment: Awesome, just wanted to be certain. Thanks @BobJones